# CSS Background color transition/slide over when load

Tags: html, css

I've found a CSS transition that works on hover just fine, it slides my background color over, but only on hover. Is there a way with CSS to make this happen on load not hover?

```
color: #FF0000;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #fff;
background-position: 0 100%;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
-webkit-transition: background-position 1s ease-in 1s;
-moz-transition: background-position 1s ease-in 1s;
transition: background-position 1s ease-in 1s;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way, using CSS alone, to delay the execution/application of an animation or transition effect until the exact moment a particular resource has been loaded. However, it can be done using JavaScript, but it's still tricky, as there is no `load`/`onload` event for background images loading (afaik).

But you could take advantage of browser's caching mechanism: it doesn't load a resource more than once if it is used several times in the page (unless under very specific circumstances, which are not default, hence don't apply here).

So the solution would be to use the background image of your element as `src` of an `<img>`, and trigger the animation inside the `onload` event of that `<img>`.

Proof of concept:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc url('https://s22849.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/placeholder-large-1.png') no-repeat center 0;
  transition: background-position 1s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
body.loaded {
  background-position: center center;
}
.placeholder {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="application/javascript">
function moveBackground() {
  document.body.classList.add('loaded');
}</script>
<img src="https://s22849.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/placeholder-large-1.png" onload="moveBackground()" class="placeholder" />
```

The key parts are:

- the URL is *exactly* the same
- the `<img>` has a height of `0` (so it's not displayed).

---

A cleaner way to do it is ***without adding the `<img>` to DOM at all***.

When changing the `src` property of an `<img>`, the browser will load it, even if it hasn't yet been added to the Document Object Model. And the `onload` event will still fire on that `<img>`, as soon as the browser is ready to render it (which means right away for already cached images).

So all you need to do is create an `<img>`, set its `src` to your element's current `backgroundImage` (stripping the surrounding `url()`) and, in its `onload` event trigger the animation. In our case, that's done by adding `loaded` class to the element.

```js
const element = document.body,
  src = window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
if (src && src.length) {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.onload = () => element.classList.add('loaded');
  img.src = src;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc url('https://s22849.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/placeholder-large-1.png') no-repeat center 0;
  transition: background-position 1s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

body.loaded {
  background-position: center center;
}
```

If you have trouble implementing the above into your project, provide more code (and I'll show you how to do it for your particular case).

As you can test, the animation is always performed ***after the image has loaded***. (Test in an incognito window or with cache disabled).

An even better test would be to use a broken URL (while making it very obvious when the element has `loaded` class - I added a red border to it). Since the resource is not found, the `loaded` class should never be applied and the animation should not be performed.

Finally, after 4 seconds, let's place a valid `backgroundImage` on the element, run our routine again and see if the background animates correctly:

```js
function onLoadBackgroundImage(element) {
  const src = window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
  if (src && src.length) {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.onload = () => element.classList.add('loaded');
    img.src = src;
  }
}
/* 4 seconds later... 
 * we actually load a valid image so we can see 
 * if the animation happens when it loads or it already happened */
setTimeout(function() {
  const el = document.body;
  el.style.backgroundImage = `url('https://s22849.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/placeholder-large-1.png')`;
  onLoadBackgroundImage(el);
}, 4000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc url('https://non-existent-url') no-repeat center 0;
  transition: background-position 1s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

body.loaded {
  background-position: center center;
  border: 3px solid red; /* let's make the application of .loaded obvious */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work if you were using CSS3 keyframes instead, for example:

```css
#banner-message {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg');
  background-color: #9ff;
  animation: animate-background linear 15s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-background {
 from { background-position: 0px 0px; } 
 to { background-position: 300px 0px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Notice how we are tweaking the css properties in the animate-background rule. THen we are just calling it in the css rule for the background container.

You're basically free to tweak any CSS3 style with this method.

Comment: This works but it needs a background-image. You can't background-position a color.

Comment: Yeah, from the CSS the author posted I guessed he had some kind of image. If the intention, however, is to move a block of background color, we can always tweak the example to displace an absolute positioned DIV inside a container with overflow hidden. @jfreak53 does this answer your question?